# Не получается в python проект установить git package

Tags: python, git, pycharm, package

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\....\Project> pip install -U git+git://github.com/iqoptionapi/iqoptionapi.git

Collecting git+git://github.com/iqoptionapi/iqoptionapi.git
  Cloning git://github.com/iqoptionapi/iqoptionapi.git to c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-wa3289ym

ERROR: Error [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл while executing command git version

ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\...\Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Вижу, что мне надо установить git в PATH, но не понимаю какой именно путь

Comment: git вообще установлен? Если да, то именно тот путь, где находится программа git.exe

Comment: Git установлен. Я не очень понял, как питону показать этот путь

Comment: PATH - это переменная среды Windows. К питону отношения не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное понял! А как ее теперь поменять?!